# typescript throwing error when starting app

Tags: typescript, yarnpkg

I have an application that has a small Typescript component.

I upgraded Yarn and a few other things and now I'm getting this error when I start the application.

Is it possible to disable Typescript for now or stop this plugin starting as I don't need it?

Any clues?

```
C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt\lib\service.js:22
        throw error;
        ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getSymbol (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31684:30)
    at resolveNameHelper (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31930:75)
    at resolveName (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31829:20)
    at resolveEntityName (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:32680:26)
    at resolveTypeReferenceName (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38485:20)
    at getTypeFromTypeReference (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38670:30)
    at getTypeFromTypeNode (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:40178:28)
    at getConstraintFromTypeParameter (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38328:72)
    at fillMissingTypeArguments (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:37877:49)
    at getTypeFromClassOrInterfaceReference (C:\workspace\client\client\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:38429:78)
```